# Is there an easy way to build a 64-bit JD2XX DLL?

Tags: java, 64-bit, usb, driver

For accessing [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/) USB boards from Java applications, I'm using the [JD2XX driver wrapper](https://jd2xx.dev.java.net/) (JD2XX.dll). It works very fine on 32-bit systems, but when it is loaded from a 64-bit JVM, it says it is impossible for a 64-bit JVM to load a 32-bit DLL. Very understandable. To get past this little problem, I install a 32-bit JVM on the 64-bit systems and it runs fine. Very simple solution, which can become very complicated to explain to a customer, though!

For this reason, I would like to create or otherwise obtain a 64-bit version of this JD2XX.dll file. I would like to know if someone ever did this successfully, or how I could proceed. I thought there should be a reference to the 32-bit dll in the ftdi-win32 project I could change for a 64-bit dll reference before recompiling everything on a 64-bit system, but I didn't find.

I would greatly appreciate any help about this. I don't feel like I'd find a way around this problem on my own anytime soon. The files I describe can be found in the most recent of [these packages](https://jd2xx.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList).

Thank you very much,

MJ

Comment: On the website for the JD2XX driver wrapper there's a link with an e-mail address of the author of the software (pbleyer). Did you try e-mailing and asking him?

Comment: Oh, lets do that! Given the age of the latest packages, I didn't even think about it.

Comment: I asked how I could go about obtaining a 64-bit version and he answered that he didn't have a 64-bit environment at the moment. I take it that it's more complicated than changing a reference somewhere and recompiling...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to generate that 64-bit DLL file. ... :)

Here is how I obtained it:

1. Downloaded the [JD2XX package](https://jd2xx.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList) (the most recent is actually dated 20071214).
2. Downloaded [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) (personal build sezero) and decompressed it in C:\ (giving C:\mingw64).
3. Brought some modifications to the JD2XX package.

   - Adjusted Makefile.conf

     - Corrected MINGW and JDK paths according to my system.
     - Selected ftdi-win32 and amd64
   - Renamed the already generated 32-bit JD2XX.dll file so that make stops telling there is nothing to be done.
   - Renamed ftdi-win32/libftd2xx.a which is 32-bit... Replaced it by a copy of ftdi-win32/amd64/ftd2xx64.lib (renamed as libftd2xx.a, of course).
4. Called C:\mingw64\bin\mingw32-make.exe from the main directory of the JD2XX package. This created a new JD2XX.DLL file which allows me to communicate with FTDI devices on my 64-bit computer without having to use a 32-bit JVM.

The [generated file for download](http://joanis.info/var/JD2XX.dll) if anyone needs it.

Comment: It was easy to add a switch in the JD2XX class (on the os.arch property) to load the 32-bit or the 64-bit DLL depending on the bitness of the running JVM (loadLibrary() call in the static block...).

Answer (score 1):

The "generated file for download" didn't work for me, so I followed the instructions and made it myself, which works:
http://dev.geogebra.org/download/lib/ftdi/JD2XX_64_2.08.17.dll

It also looks like you should be able to build a 64-bit dll on a 32-bit system (or even on linux) by downloading the correct version of mingw-w64:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/sezero_4.5_20111101/

Also, some of the links are out of date. These are current:

d2xx.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/d2xx/trunk/

www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm